# не отображается модальное окно в Mozilla Firefox, а остальных браузерах отображается

Tags: html, css, popup, modal

Исправляю косяки на сверстанном сайте, и попалась такая задача - собственно поп-ап не отображается в Мозилле. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Вот так отображается в Chrome и Safari

[image: Вот так отображается в Chrome и Safari]

А вот так в Мозилле

[image: А вот так в Мозилле]

Comment: если это попап а не модалка, то тут проблема в самом браузере, он по умолчанию их все блокирует

Comment: Проблема может быть в блокировщике рекламы - если он есть в Мозилле, отключите и попробуйте без него

Comment: @humster_spb да, оказалось дело в блокировщике. Спасибо!

Comment: @MaksimChernyshev, дело в том, что у себя-то Вы его отключили, но другие посетители сайта, у которых включен блокировщик, столкнутся с аналогичной проблемой и не увидят содержимое окна. То есть проблема-то не решена :) Скорее всего, в названиях классов или идентификаторов в разметке встречаются т.н. стоп-слова типа class="reklama" или id="advertisement". Их надо переименовать. Вообще исключить из разметки любые названия, которые могут восприниматься блокировщиком как рекламные блоки.